# C# Linq to query a List to see if a value is empty or null

Tags: c#, linq

Let's say I have an USAddressModel

```
 class Address {
      public string addressline1 {get; set;}
      public string addressline2 {get; set;}
      public string city {get; set;}
      public string state {get; set;}
      public string zip {get; set;}
 }
```

If I have an object in my C# code like

```
var customer = response.Result; // List<Address>
```

How can I query this list using Linq to create two lists

the first list should contain the minimum required to ship an item to the customer (addressline1, city state and zip).

the second list should be those who have not filled out the complete mailing address. (like only provided a zip or addressline2, city state, zip)

I know that a person could have typed addressline1 into the addressline2 field but for the purpose of this, I was just trying to learn how to use query in C# with linq.

Would this problem be better solved using Lambda?

Thank you for helping.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest to try it in an naive way first, before trying something advanced like LINQ. How would you do it if you'd never heard anything about LINQ? What steps do  you need to achieve that? Those steps build up your algorithm. Afterwards translate that to some program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var listOne = response.Result.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.addressline1) &&
 !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.city) &&
 !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.state) &&
 !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.zip)).ToList();

var listTwo = response.Result.Where(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.addressline1) ||
 string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.city) ||
 string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.state) ||
 string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.zip)).ToList();
```

Comment: why use .Where instead of .Any?

Comment: The OP asked for `List`

Comment: @softwareisfun Because `Any()` will return `true` or `false` to tell you if searched element exists. `Where()` will return all elements that match in a `List`. It's like "Tell me if `Any` element exists", and "Return all elements `Where` address is not empty".

Answer (score 1):

As one list is the supplementary of the other you can do it this way too:

```
var customer = response.Result;  
var listOne = customer.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.addressline1) &&    
                                      !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.city) &&
                                      !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.state) &&
                                      !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.zip)).ToList();
var listTow = customer.Where(x => !listOne(y => y.Equals(x))).ToList();
```